# Powershell, rename at -Destination a folder copied with its content: is it possible with 1 command?

Tags: powershell

I'm copying a folder with its content to another dir. like this:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\docs1\article-title-master" -Destination "C:\docs2\articles" -recurse -Force
```

Is it possible with 1 command also to rename folder `article-title-master` at -Destination? At -Destination only, not in -Path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the name of the folder in `-Destination` like this : (as you did in you exemple)

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\docs1\article-title-master" -Destination "C:\docs2\articles\new-article-title" -Recurse -Force
```

The original folder name "article-title-master" will remain unchanged in the source path.